# Actualizar mi IP usando DynDns en Python

Tags: python

Estoy verificando un pequeño programa para actualizar mi IP en DynDns.

Lo que hago es lo siguiente:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import requests
import json
user = "email"
password = "pass"
checkip = "http://thisisnt.com/api/getRemoteIp.php"
dynupdate = "https://members.dyndns.com/nic/update"
print "starting. Get current IP..."
ipraw = requests.get(checkip)
if ipraw.status_code is not 200:
  raise "Cannot get IP address"
  exit

ip = ipraw.json()['REMOTE_ADDR']
print "Remote IP: " + ip
print "updating..."
# update dyndns
headers = {'user-agent': 'mPythonClient/0.0.3'}
dyn = requests.get(dynupdate, \
              headers=headers, \
              auth=(user, password), \
              params={'hostname': 'xjhdshsdhagsafhg.ddns.net', \
                       'myip': ip, \
                       'wildcard': 'NOCHG', \
                       'mx': 'MX', \
                       })
if dyn.status_code is not 200:
  print "Update failed. HTTP Code: " + str(dyn.status_code)
if "good" in dyn.text:
  print "update successful.."
else:
  print "Update unsuccessful: " + dyn.text.strip()
```

Creo haber puesto los datos y los parámetros correctamente, pero el problema es que cuando lo ejecuto la actualización no es exitosa:

[image: Actualización no exitosa: badauth]

Mi pregunta es: ¿cómo podría hacer para que me devolviese mi IP correctamente actualizada? Siempre se queda en:

```
print "Update unsuccessful: " + dyn.text.strip()
```

Y yo lo que querría hacer es que se actualizara con la nueva IP y la imprimiese:

```
print "update successful.." + ip
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como se puede deducir del error que te devuelve el servidor al hacer la petición (`badauth`), el problema está con el método de autentificación que estás usando.

Si echas un vistazo a la [documentación de Dyn](https://help.dyn.com/remote-access-api/perform-update/), verás que el uso de usuario y contraseña para autorizar las peticiones **ha quedado obsoleto**, y por lo tanto tienes que usar un `updater client key` (clave para el cliente actualizador).

Puedes generar una de esas claves desde [tu cuenta](http://account.dyn.com/).

Una vez la tengas, pon esa nueva clave en vez de `pass`:

```
password = "pass"
```

Y cambia el endpoint de la API por el nuevo:

```
dynupdate = "https://members.dyndns.org/v3/update"
```

También puedes eliminar las claves `wildcard` y `mx` del diccionario `params`, ya que son innecesarios.

¡Listo! Al ejecutar tu script debería funcionar correctamente. Recuerda añadir la línea que mencionas en tu pregunta, para que muestre la nueva IP como quieres:

```
if "good" in dyn.text:
    print "Update successful... " + ip
```